# If I delete image from S3 bucket, does AWS delete recognized face from Amazon Rekognition collection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can't store images on AWS because of the law in my country, but I need the **Amazon Rekognition** service for the `SearchFaces` feature.

I have an idea to do the following:

1. Add image to S3 bucket
2. Add face from image to Amazon Rekognition collection. (As I know AWS stores faces as a vector, not actual image, and it means that is okay by law.)
3. Delete image from S3 bucket
4. Use Amazon Rekognition collection

**Question:** I am very curious, does Amazon delete all relations when I delete main image from s3 bucket or it will leave vector face in Amazon Recognition collection as it is?

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no linkage from the Rekognition Faces collection back to the source images. What if they were on your computer, for example?

Rekognition stores a vector of facial features, but not the image itself. So, while you can't reverse the feature vector to re-create the original source image, you *can* use the feature vector to find facial matches for newly-presented images. So bear that in mind when you are trying to understand how to meet your compliance requirements.

Comment: I have just found in documentation that every face record has `ExternalImageId` and it confused me. So, following your answer deleting an image will not affect saved face vector in my collection. Thx!

Comment: The ExternalImageId can be used for whatever correlation purposes you want. It's just a piece of metadata associated with the face vector. You might typically set it to an ID in your database associated with a given person, or you could store the URI of an image in S3 if you want. But Rekognition doesn't do anything special with it.